# What happened to my background music?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

So, I have this app and I put in some background music to make it better.  Everything was working fine, but I decided the background music wasn't as good as it could be.  I found another music file, put it my project, then updated the file name in the code and ... no sound.  Confused, I put the original file name back into the code and ... still no sound.  So ... what worked before is no longer working - and I've not done any updates or anything to xcode/etc.  Anyone wanna take a stab at how to fix this?  Or ... How it could even happen so I can avoid it in the future?  Here is the code:

```
import AVFoundation

var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

 // old function, works in another app but not this one ... derp

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(
        filename, withExtension: nil)
    if (url == nil) {
        println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }

    var error: NSError? = nil
    backgroundMusicPlayer =
        AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
        println("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}
```

Oh, and I am calling the player to play in the viewdidload:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        playBackgroundMusic("violetshrine.caf")
```

I've read all kinds of articles on working with sound in swift ... seems there are lots of different methods and what not, but this is the code that was working before, and is even working in another app I'm building along with this one ... so I'm really confused (the life of a newb).  Thank you to anyone who takes time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All image, audio etc. files need to be a part of bundle resources. Please check the following 2 points

1. Make sure the file you added is actually added to your build target and not just the Xcode hierarchy.

[image]

2. Make sure you delete the app from device/simulator and clean the project (`Product->Clean` in Xcode app menu) and run the project again any time you add/remove/update a resource file.

This is assuming your code is/was working fine (as you claim in your question).

Comment: Wow!  Thanks lukya!!!  Can't believe it was really that simple.  I had done many cleans etc, but I didn't know to check the little box for the target of the file -- I had even read about doing that in the file inspector, but didn't understand until you posed that picture.  Thank you so much!!!  It works again, yay!!!